# Unable to simulate deadlock in java with nested synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, simulation, deadlock

I was playing around with threads in Java and decided to simulate deadlock situation but was unable do it.

Following code couldn't result in deadlock situation before adding statement between nested synchronized blocks:

```
public class Main {

    public static class Account {

        String name;

        AtomicInteger money = new AtomicInteger(0);

        void deposit(final int amount){
            money.addAndGet(amount);
        }

        void withdraw(final int amount){
            money.getAndAdd(-amount);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, Exception {
        int n = 5000;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> transfer(account1, account2, 1));
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> transfer(account2, account1, 2));
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
         
            
        }
    }

    public static void transfer(Account from, Account to, int amount){
        System.out.println("Hello from :" + Thread.currentThread());
        synchronized(from){
         // If bellow line is uncommented deadlock will occur, otherwise not
         // System.out.println();
            synchronized(to){
                from.withdraw(amount);
                to.deposit(amount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By my understanding this should end up in deadlock especially when runing simulation 5k times and  but application would terminate successfully after setting n to arbitrary large int. After adding simple println statement between two nested sync statement:

```
synchronized(from){
            **System.out.println();**
            synchronized(to){
```

I got deadlock.

I am confused why it is not happening when there is no statement between syncs. Am I missing something or there is some inherent Java mechanism (optimisation) which gives one thread priority over nested synchronize if there are no intermediate statement? Or it is just my machine/JVM/OS combo?

Comment: Most likely the I/O that's happening causes the scheduler to decide that's a good time to switch threads, or something. You definitely can't rely on that type of behaviour.

Comment: Concurrency problems are hard for a reason. Sometimes you can't know how to reproduce them intentionally.

Comment: If you synchronize on the objects in different orders you will deadlock. If you always synchronize in the same order you won't.

Answer (score 1):

> By my understanding this should end up in deadlock.

No. It *could* end up in deadlock, but without those `println` calls the chances are slim. When I say, "slim," I'm talking about the kind of slim chances where; a company I worked for tested a new release of a product for several weeks, and after all the tests passed, we shipped it out to a dozen or so clients. The clients then ran with it for half a year before a deadlock happened on *one* of those client's servers, disrupting their e-commerce web site. (*I* got the fun job of figuring out what happened by studying the 4Gb core file that they sent back to us.)

Without those `println` calls, what is *MUCH* more likely to happen is; either thread locks both of the mutexes before the other gets a chance to try, it does its work, and then the other thread has its turn.